# Issues with FCM Notification Link Redirection and Image Display on iOS (PWA), and Duplicate Notifications

Tags: ios, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications, progressive-web-apps

I'm using Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) to send push notifications to Android, Web, and iOS devices, including a PWA on iOS. My implementation in Python successfully sends notifications with a link, and it works as intended on Android and Web. However, I'm encountering some issues specific to iOS:

Link Redirection on iOS: Notifications received on iOS devices (especially within a PWA) don't redirect to the provided URL upon clicking. The same setup works for Android and Web. How can I enable URL redirection for iOS?

Image Display in Notifications on iOS: My notifications include an image, which is displayed in Android and Web notifications. However, I'm not sure if iOS supports image display in FCM notifications, especially within a PWA context. Can iOS display images in notifications sent via FCM?

Duplicate Notifications: Regardless of the platform, I'm receiving each notification twice. Is there something in my implementation causing this behavior? and my Front-end is next.js

Here's the relevant part of my Python code for sending notifications

from firebase_admin import messaging
from firebase_admin.messaging import WebpushConfig, WebpushFCMOptions, AndroidConfig, AndroidNotification, APNSConfig, APNSPayload, Aps

```
def send_to_firebase_cloud_messaging(token, title, body, icon, image, url):
    # [Code omitted for brevity]

    try:
        message = messaging.Message(
            # [Notification setup for all platforms]
            # Android-specific configuration
            android=AndroidConfig(
                notification=AndroidNotification(
                    icon=icon,
                    color='#f45342',
                    click_action=url
                )
            ),
            # iOS-specific configuration
            apns=APNSConfig(
                payload=APNSPayload(
                    aps=Aps(
                        badge=42,
                        category=url
                    )
                )
            ),
            # Web-specific configuration
            webpush=WebpushConfig(
                fcm_options=WebpushFCMOptions(link=url)
            ),
            token=registration_token,
        )

        response = messaging.send(message)
        return response
    except Exception as e:
        return str(e)
```

Any insights or suggestions for these iOS-specific issues and the duplicate notifications problem would be greatly appreciated.